# Disabling USB Port

Tags: windows-10, usb, motherboard

I have an external USB Webcam. It has a light sensor embedded, so as soon the room is dark, its LED turns on.

The problem is that I prefer a dark room as my workspace which means the LED of my webcam is always on. I have to attend video calls so I can't throw it away and plugging it and unplugging it is annoying.

Is there any way I can power that port (integrated to motherboard) and enable it when I want to? My OS is Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Small piece of black electrical tape over the LED, or white so you can see it but dimmed? My workspace is covered in them;)

Comment: seems it is LED for low-light surroundings not an activity LED...so tape would be impractical, maybe cover it with a cloth/hat/sock..? so you will not need to unplu/re-plug it when needed...

Comment: Seems legit , thank yaa!!

Answer (score -1):

Did You check solution provided here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267236/how-disable-and-enable-usb-port-via-command-prompt/42574275

Or by using DeviceManager Uninstal device connected to USB port when not needed.

Comment: This disables the USB port, but doesn't cut off the power supply to USB port.